# Converting 2-line text file to 2 arrays

Tags: arrays, vb.net, text-files

I have a text file that i have to convert to two arrays(each line into array). It has a header line(1st line) and the value line(2nd line), it looks like this:

```
    AD1|PL0|EO2|DS2|OE4...
    42|0|321|3|56...
```

Basically, i need to put the lines in separate arrays so if i, for example, delelete the third item in first line(EO2), the third item in second line(321) also deletes. So far i have done something like this:

```
    Public Function FillArrayList(ByVal path As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim lines As New List(Of String)

    Try
        Dim reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(path)

        While Not (reader.Peek() = -1)
            lines.Add(reader.ReadLine())
        End While

        reader.Close()
        reader.Dispose()
    Catch ex As IOException
        lines.Add(ex.ToString())
    End Try


    Return lines
End Function
```

This reads the file and puts the lines in different arrays, but i cant figure how to use the Split() function in this one so the items are splitted.

Comment: Where is your attempt to use the Split() function?

Comment: There is a _File.ReadAllLines_ to replace everything above

Comment: Just trying to get a sense of what you really want. Do you want an object of arrays that contain each full index data? Like the third index would be an array containing all the third items from all lines?

Comment: @JohnnyPrescott Im new to programming so i dont actually know how to perform or explain what exactly i have to do with the arrays but the reason i am doing this is that i have to remove certain items in my text file(like i explained in the question) with a program so i dont have to do it manually.

Comment: See my answer to the best of what I understand.

Answer (score -1):

Fill the array like that and then you can delete the third entry like you said.

There might be some minor error as I hadto do the code on my phone. :)

```
Dim lines as String = file.readlines()
Dim array2d(lines.Length, 1) As String

For l As Integer To lines.Count - 1
    Dim countEl As Integer = lines(l).split("|").Count()
    If array2d.GetLenght(1) < countEl Then
        ReDim Preserve array2d(lines.Lenght, countEl) As String
    End If
    For e As Interger To lines(l).split("|").Count - 1
        array2d(l, e) = lines(l).split("|")(e)
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Didnt quite understand what this code does and it caused a lot of errors i dont know how to fix :D

Comment: Like I said. I'm still at work so can't test. This is a simple 2d array that you fill up that will contain your data in the way you wanted. Index (0,0) is "AD1", (0,2) is "EO2", (1,2) is "321", etc.

Comment: Maybe you want to read on basic function in the official documentation. If you can't debug two simple nested For loop to fill this, you might not be ready yet. :)

Comment: And people are downvoting without commenting or submitting anvalid answer. Common...

Comment: It wasnt me that downvoted, btw. I said i wanted to remove the third element as an example, i have many text files and i dont know i wich position that EO2 will be so i dont think a 2D array will be the correct way to do this.

Comment: That depend what the end goal is with your code. I think I didnt quite catxh what you wanted to do. Maybe a List(Of Array) is what you want to use? Code would be similar with two nested loop still but you would have access to list.add and list.remove. you also have DataTablr which behave more like a spreadsheet. Again, depend on your need.

Comment: The end goal is that when i remove an item from the first line, the item from the second line also removes. And i dont even know the correct way of doing that